# My dropdown menu on mobile devices doesn't work

Tags: html, css

When I press the menu item on the top right side of my webpage it doesn't collapse. I have checked my code and it seems to be okay.

The website with the problem is: `www.kemnet.be`

I have tried putting everything in the block and made minor changes to my `jquery` and `CSS`. 
I have this from a theme and added the original code to my site for testing but the dropdown still doesn't show.

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaqued" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="bounce-in no-display animated bounceIn appear" href="index.html"></a> <img src="images\white.png">
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#praktisch">Praktisch </a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-us">Onze Visie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Ons Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Ons Aanbod </a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog">Nieuws</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="border" href="https://www.mtc-it4.be/patient/index.html#/appointments/day/bjNkcWkyQmFRMkpDVTRFNndleFgzSlRvdC9TSU1YOXdJWklnQ2ZtMDhjcEJCYWl6RlREMWxyOGlZY2FSUk10WQ==" target="_blank">Maak een afspraak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I don't receive any error messages tho.

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: do you use font awesome??

Comment: Yeah i do use font-awesome

Comment: Getting console Error: `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4`

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced    `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>` with classic way.

```
 <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaqued" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="bounce-in no-display animated bounceIn appear" href="index.html"></a> <img src="images\white.png">
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#praktisch">Praktisch </a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-us">Onze Visie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Ons Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Ons Aanbod </a></li>
                <li><a href="#blog">Nieuws</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="border" href="https://www.mtc-it4.be/patient/index.html#/appointments/day/bjNkcWkyQmFRMkpDVTRFNndleFgzSlRvdC9TSU1YOXdJWklnQ2ZtMDhjcEJCYWl6RlREMWxyOGlZY2FSUk10WQ==" target="_blank">Maak een afspraak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v61aeg5r/1/

Comment: if you want to use font awesome icon then try <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>

Comment: i tested this live and still have the same problem.

Comment: its giving error for jquery. Please update your jquery version.

Comment: yours jquery version is 1.8.2. please use version 2.x or 3.x

Comment: remove old one <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>. or comment that line

Comment: This solves the menu problem but now my images are gone

Comment: Its Working. Images are loaded.

Comment: yeah because i changed the jquery to version 1.9, but everything works now so it's fine. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: wokring both now.